# Insertion Sort - Why does the code run correctly for certain sets of values while throws Array Index Out of Bounds Exception for other sets

Tags: java, sorting, data-structures, insertion-sort

The code works perfectly fine when first input is the smallest value in the array whereas, for all other cases, the code throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException -1

Test Input1: 6,8,7,11,9 (Works for this input)

Test Input2: 10,9,7,12,1 (Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1)

Please share what could be the reason for this and how to resolve this issue.

```
//SortingMain.java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SortingMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int data[] = new int[5];
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        InsertionSort obj = new InsertionSort();
        System.out.println("Enter the numbers in array:");
        for(int i=0; i<5;i++) {
            data[i]=input.nextInt();
        }
        obj.insertionSort(data);
        System.out.println("Elements after sorting");
        for(int i=0; i<5;i++) {
            System.out.println(data[i] + " ,");
        }
        input.close();
    }
}
```

```
//InsertionSort.java
public class InsertionSort {
    public void insertionSort(int data[]) {
        int i,j,key;
        for(i=1;i<data.length;i++) {
            key=data[i];
            j=i;
            while(data[j-1]>key && j>=1) {
                data[j] = data[j-1];
                j--;
            }
            data[j] = key;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have the condition in your while loop like this: `while (j >= 1 && data[j - 1] > key) { ... }` i.e. `j >= 1` should be checked first and only if this is satisfied, `data[j-1] > key` should be checked.

This is because first it should be checked that the index I'm going to access from the `data` is valid and then access it, otherwise `IndexOutOfBoundException` will occur.